# PlayerPrefs не работает?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вот как я сохраняю:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Menu : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Sensitivity"))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Sensitivity", 1f);
        }
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
    public void OnSensChange(float value)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Sensitivity", value);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

И загружаю (в другой сцене):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    private float Sensitivity;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Sensitivity = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Sensitivity");
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

И значение не сохраняется.

Answer (score 2):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TestPlayerPrefs : MonoBehaviour
{ // в вопросе операционные скобки одни тут другие, где codeStyle?
    // constants
    // статику и константы всё-таки пишут в начале
    private const string kSensitivity = "Sensitivity";

    // Private vars? private fields! 
    // переменные в функциях а это поля класса
    [SerializeField] private float _defaultSensitivity = 1;
    private float _sensitivity;

    // Accessors? propertys!
    // свойства обычно после полей
    public float Sensitivity => _sensitivity;

    // подобные комменты, в которых написано, что белое это белое,
    // а чёрное это не красное, называют излишними, это грех

    private void Start () 
    {
        LoadSensitivity();
    }

    public void SaveSensitivity (float value) 
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(kSensitivity, value);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        // то Log в начале, то в конце, надо хоть какой-то codeStyle соблюдать
        Debug.Log($"Save Sensitivity = {value}");
    }

    private void LoadSensitivity () // зачем тут public?
    {
        _sensitivity = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(kSensitivity, _defaultSensitivity);
        Debug.Log($"Load Sensitivity = {_sensitivity}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Загружается 1 раз.

```
public class Foo
{
    private const string ValueKey = "Value";
    private const float DefaultValue = 1f;
    private static Foo _instance;

    public static Foo Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new Foo();
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private float _value;

    public float Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            if (_value != value)
            {
                _value = value;
                Save();
            }
        }
    }

    private Foo ()
    {
        Load();
    }

    private void Load ()
    {
        _value = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(ValueKey, DefaultValue);
    }

    private void Save ()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(ValueKey, _value);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode _randomValueKey = KeyCode.Z;
    
    private void Start ()
    {
        Debug.Log(Foo.Instance.Value);
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(_randomValueKey))
            RandomValue();
    }

    private void RandomValue ()
    {
        float NewValue = Random.Range(0, 100f);
        Foo.Instance.Value = NewValue;
        Debug.Log(NewValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Можете пожалуйста пояснить?

Comment: @ТимонЯблоков `singletone` называется. Я хз что у тебя за проблемы, `PlayerPrefs` работает.